# Cms group system, unique domains

Tags: cms, top-level-domains

I apologise is the question isnt worded quite right or too simplistic in nature.

I am currently planning on building a new cms system that allows for user generated pages. 
similar to groups on facebook, most of the content to be provided directly by the user, i.e. news stories, pictures etc.

It is important that each "group" is hosted under its own domain, 
Are there any tutorials anyone can point me to , to understand how to build this type of system or guide me to the correct concept behind this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try the [buddypress plugin](http://www.buddypress.org/) for [wordpress](http://www.wordpress.org/). Buddypress has a group feature, and if you also [enable wordpress multisite](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network) while running buddypress each group will also have their own blog.

UPDATE: this is more of a tutorial:

1. Download and install wordpress: http://www.wordpress.org/
2. Put WordPress in multisite mode: http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network
3. Download and install buddypress: http://www.buddypress.org/

Comment: thanks for the advice, i really wanted to do it through a tutorial structure, im more on a learning mission. Currently using codeignitor, so hoepfully something based around that

Comment: I updated the answer to make it more tutorial like. And no, wordpress and buddypress don't use codeignitor